# .htaccess redirect old subdomain to new subdomain - remove anything after domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have a very old subdomain that I'm planning to shutdown in a few weeks, but as an interim procedure, I have to redirect all pages on said subdomain to a new subdomain.  There are too many to do individually, and the SEO ramifications are no big deal.

That said, anything after oldsubdomain.domain.com/ needs to be eliminated from the process altogether - so that we end up on newsubdomain.domain.com.  With no query strings...no directories.  Nothing after the .com.  Zero, zip, zilch.

Can't thank this community enough for the help!  I'm at a loss at the moment.
Please and thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep this rule as very first rule in old domain's site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =oldsubdomain.domain.com
RewriteRule ^ http://newsubdomain.domain.com/? [L,R=301]
```

`/?` will strip off any previous query string

Comment: Outstanding!  This absolutely worked for me.  It's weird because I tried the ? at the end of my previous code and the directories kept showing up.  But with what you provided, it works perfectly.  Thank you!